# Octave and multiple Bode plots

Tags: octave

I'm teaching myself Octave and as a motivational exercise am attempting to create some Bode plots.  I'd like to create a plot that has multiple curves for different values of a parameter in a transfer function, for example the time constant of a simple RC filter.  I'm trying to do it as follows:

```
tau = [1,2,3]
for i = tau
    g(i) = tf(1,[tau(i),1])
endfor

bode(g(1),g(2),g(3))
```

But it doesn't work, I get the error

> error: octave_base_value::imag (): wrong type argument `struct'

However, it works fine if there are not multiple arguments to the bode command and the last line is simply:

```
bode(g(1))
```

Any advice as to where I've gone wrong would be appreciated - is there a better way to do what I want to do?

Comment: I tried your code in Matlab and it worked fine, so I do believe this is an issue with Octave.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate.  Thanks for testing it out for me.

Comment: If it helps, here's an output using an older version (Octave 3.0.3): http://pastebin.com/25HA3YUW

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with the following sequence (with octave 3.2.4 on debian):

```
bode(g(1))
set (findobj (gcf, "type", "axes"), "nextplot", "add")
bode(g(2))
bode(g(3))
```

The second command is similar to `hold on` but it works when there are subplots; I found it [here](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Multiple-bode-plots-fail-on-same-figure-td1670758.html).

Comment: A couple of things to note - while it does add plotline, it does not add new items to the legend. Also persists while figure window is not closed, which is kind of nice for manual testing, if you can keep track of plots yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own code:

```
subplot(211), hold on
subplot(212), hold on
tau = [1,2,3]
for i = 1:length(tau),
   g(i) = tf(1,[tau(i),1]);
   bode(g(i))
endfor
```

The problem with this solution is that you cannot identify a specific plot. You cannot access figure properties through `bode()` function directly.

Here then a plausible solution to bring you colorful plots:

```
colorsplot = ["b","m","g"]
tau = [1,2,3]
g = tf(1,[tau(1),1]);
[mag, ph, w] = bode(g);
subplot(211), semilogx(w,20*log(mag)), hold on
subplot(212), semilogx(w,ph), hold on
for i = 2:length(tau),
  g = tf(1,[tau(i),1]);
  [mag, ph, waux] = bode(g,w);
  subplot(211), semilogx(w,20*log(mag),colorsplot(i))
  subplot(212), semilogx(w,ph,colorsplot(i))
endfor
```